# How do I get the record ID's for a bulk data insert using sfdx CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, bulk-api

I'm trying to use sfdx-cli to perform bulk-insert jobs, but can't find a way to access the batch results on a per row level.

I see that the command `force:data:bulk:status` informs you of how many records succeeded/failed but doesn't tell you which ones.

I've tried sending a GET request to the following URI `https://instance_name—api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job/jobid/batch/batchId/result` (as documented here) by using the batch id and job id returned from sfdx-cli but keep get the error "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))".

For instance_name I'm using the string in the salesforce URL preceding ".my.salesforce.com" but I'm loading into our Sandbox so it's "company_instance--sandbox_name".